# Calculate the derivative using limit definition.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

This is the function $f(x)$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3x-2}}$ .
I wrote that $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\frac{\sqrt{3x+3h-2}}{3x+3h-2}-\frac{\sqrt{3x-2}}{3x-2}}{h}.$$
I am not able to continue further.

Comment: Multiply by $\frac {\frac {1}{\sqrt {3(x+h) - 2}} + \frac {1}{\sqrt {3x - 2}}}{\frac {1}{\sqrt {3(x+h) - 2}} + \frac {1}{\sqrt {3x - 2}}}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:**

Note that

$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{3(x+h)-2}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3x-2}}&=\frac{\frac{1}{3(x+h)-2}-\frac{1}{3x-2}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3(x+h)-2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3x-2}}}\\\\
&=\frac{\frac{-3h}{(3(x+h)-2)(3x-2)}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3(x+h)-2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3x-2}}}
\end{align}$$

Divide by $h$ and let $h\to 0$.

Comment: You're welcome. My pleasure.

Comment: And feel free to both up vote and accept an answer as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a = \sqrt{3x+h-2}$ and $b = \sqrt{3x-2}$, then $a^2 - b^2 = h$ which means $h \to 0$ as $a \to b$. So we've:

$$ \lim_{a \to b} \frac{1/a-1/b}{a^2-b^2}  = \lim_{a \to b} \frac{b-a}{(ab)(a+b)(a-b)} = - \lim_{a \to b} \frac{1}{ab(a+b)} = -\frac{1}{2 b^3} = -\frac{1}{2\sqrt{(3x-2)^3}.} $$